# Issues parsing xml array from curl call

Tags: php, xml, arrays, parsing

I am having serious issues parsing this xml array using curl. I only need the click_id printed on each new row. Does someone have an example of how I can pull this. I am using curl and get the response below in the variable $result. I am using php.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfClick xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://cakemarketing.com/api/1/">
<Click>
<click_id>7458165</click_id>
<request_session_id>7901644</request_session_id>
<click_date>2011-09-08T13:53:37.143</click_date>
<offer_id>10346</offer_id>
<advertiser_id>1050</advertiser_id>
<campaign_id>6527</campaign_id>

</Click>
<Click>
<click_id>7459318</click_id>
<request_session_id>7903011</request_session_id>
<click_date>2011-09-08T14:41:37.953</click_date>
<offer_id>10346</offer_id>
<advertiser_id>1050</advertiser_id>
<campaign_id>6527</campaign_id>
</Click>
```

Comment: What are your issues, what code are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use XPath with the help of this class http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

A more simple method is to use regex (but I discourage this approach)